# Css loaded but not applied from other server

Tags: javascript, php

I need to import styles from other server.
I have tried this code : 

But, styles and js loaded not applied. Please help me to fix this bug. Thank you in advance.

Comment: please post what you have tried..

Comment: no code here :)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: "<link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.otherserver.com/styles/style.css?v=v1">"

Comment: first of all, get sure that the resource does exist on otherserver. second, check if otherserver allows you to use its resources.

Comment: @marmeladze otherserver exist and css file loaded i can see the css code in browser . My problem is style not applied